# Angular Timer - UTC to local time's timestamp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, timer

I'm unsure how to get the [Angular Timer directive](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer) to display countdown in local time? My server app (Laravel) returns time in UTC (ISO 8601).

For example:
`2016-08-06T09:11:01Z`
This is about 7 hours late compared to my timezone.

The [angular relative date](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/angular-relative-date) directive would return correct localized time:
`{{feed.date | relativeDate}}`
`Output: 2 mins ago`

But I'm not sure how to convert that to the timestamp that can be used for the timer to display in local time? This wouldn't show the right `end-time` in my timezone.

`<timer end-time="feed.time*1000">@{{hhours}}h</timer>`

`feed.time` is something like `1470448297`

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment),

To get relative time :

```
<span am-time-ago="feed.date"></span>
```

You can check docs for other applications.